# when to use double quotes in if-condition in shell scripts

Tags: shell, unix

I'm learning shell scripting for an exam and in our teachers book at one place he writes in an example the following:

```
# This script expects a folder path as an argument.
cd $1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "Folder not found"; exit 1; fi
```

In another example however he writes:

```
# This script expects one argument
if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then echo "Missing Parameter"; exit 1; fi
```

Now, when do I have to put the tested argument within the square brackets in double quotes and when not?

I mean, $? in this case represents a number. However, $# in this example also represents a number and not a string (although everything is a string). But why is $# double-quoted and $? not?

Comment: `echo "Folder not found"` demonstrates horrific technique.  There are many reasons `cd` can fail.  Fortunately, it will report a reasonable error, so the shell script should just exit rather than appending meaningless text on the wrong output stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, since Bash guarantees that both are numbers.

If there was a possibility that a variable might be a string, potentially with control characters or spaces, then it is necessary to quote.

Comment: thanks to both of you! presumably the "risk" of a whitespace was the reason for putting "$#" in double quotes in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing. $values represent variables and will be used as variables inside and outside the quotes.

Comment: Strictly true only if the value of the variable does not contain whitespace.